# get count in relation table in yii2 Activerecord

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, yii2

I have two table for post and user. I want to show post count of user in users list gridview. In yii 1 I use this in model to define a relation for this purpose:

```
'postCount' => array(self::STAT, 'Post', 'author',
            'condition' => 'status = ' . Post::ACTIVE),

...
User:find...().with('postCount').....
```

But i don't know how to implement this in Yii2 to get count of post in User:find():with('...') to show in gridview.
Anyone try this in yii2?

Comment: See https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/2179#issuecomment-91845257.

Answer (score 9):

Here is an example of what I did and it seems to work fine so far. It was used to get a count of comments on a post. I simply used a standard active record count and created the relation with the where statement using $this->id and the primary key of the entry its getting a count for.

```
public function getComment_count()
{
    return Comment::find()->where(['post' => $this->id])->count();
}
```

Just a passing it along...

Answer (score 4):

You can try the code below:

```
User::find()->joinWith('posts',true,'RIGHT JOIN')->where(['user.id'=>'posts.id'])->count();
```

Or if you want to specify a user count:

```
//user id 2 for example
User::find()->joinWith('posts',true,'RIGHT JOIN')->where(['user.id'=>'posts.id','user.id'=>2])->count();
```

Please note that, `posts` is a relation defined in your `User` model like below:

```
public function getPosts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Comment: I want information of user with post count, username, email, Post count

Comment: @ArazJafaripur well, change `count()` to `one()` or `all()` and get its count

Comment: The datatype for return should be ActiveQuery, because data must to show in gridview. ->all getting error.

Comment: ummm :) pass it as `query` in your `dataProvider`. Take a look at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#filtering-data and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html countryman :)

Comment: I do all of this and showing gridview, just i paste part of code here. now in gridview, I want to show count of post each user created. in yii 1 I do this as well like above code, but in Yii2 I don't know how to do this!

Answer (score 2):

Well still I think for those who it may concern, if you JUST want the count a select and not the data it will be better use this instead imho:

```
$count = (new \yii\db\Query())
->select('count(*)')
->from('table')
->where(['condition'=>'value'])
->scalar();

echo $count;
```