# Yii2 - show count of relation data in gridview using activerecord

Tags: mysql, gridview, activerecord, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have two tables Agencies and Agents, I want to show the number of agents each agency has using a count query ("agents" table has a column called 'agency_id'). there is an [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894987/get-count-in-relation-table-in-yii2-activerecord) here on stackoverflow but it's not completely answered.

Here's what I tried so far:

In Agencies Model (to get the agent count in agencies gridview):

```
 */
public function getAgents()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Professionnels::className(), ['agency_id' => 'id']);

}
```

In Agents Model (to get the agency name in agents gridview):

```
public function getAgencies()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Agencies::className(), ['id' => 'agency_id']);
}
```

In Agencies view that shows the gridview:

```
'columns' => [
        ....,
         ['label' => 'Agents Number','attribute' => 'count(agents.id'),]
```

And in the AgenciesSearch:

```
$query = Agencies::find()->with('agents');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the `count()` function on your relationship in the `value` attribute of your column:

```
'columns' => [
....,
  [
    'label' => 'Agents Number',
    'attribute' => 'agents',
    'value' => function ($model) { return $model->getAgents()->count();}
  ]
```

Another option would be to create a new method to get the Agents count in your Agency model:

```
public function getAgentsCount()
{
    return $this->getAgents()->count();
}
```

And call refer to it in your column:

```
'columns' => [
    ....,
      [
        'label' => 'Agents Number',
        'attribute' => 'agentsCount',
      ]
```

Comment: It works as charm. I still have to define sorting & filtring but THANK you man